# Azure Management API - Special characters (/) in path parameter

Tags: azure, python-3.8, azure-management-api

I am working on retrieving values from Azure App Configuration store.

API being used: GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/{configStoreName}/keyValues/{keyValueName}?api-version=2023-03-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/%7BconfigStoreName%7D/keyValues/%7BkeyValueName%7D?api-version=2023-03-01)

The {keyValueName} contains special character '/' and azure api response is coming back as 404

Sample {keyValueName}  value: '/sub1/rg1'

I tried using the encoding mechanism urllib.parse.quote_plus(keyValueName) but still the response is 404.  I am using the python3.8 requests module to send a call to the api. Please suggest.

The alternative approach to use the connecting string and get the value is working. However it requires me to give the SP 'Contributor' role which I am trying to avoid.